# Laravel products sold in the last year

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to show the sales made in the last year by dividing them by months. I wrote the code, but how can I send it to the view and display it?

```
$month = 0;

while ($month < 12) {
    $date = new DateTime('NOW');
    $date->modify('-'.$month.'month');
    $formatted_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $month_sales = Order::where('created_at', '>=', $formatted_date)
        ->sum('order_price');
    $month++;
}
```

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/984422) when asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So not much info provided but i would do this based on your existing code. (assuming your using blade for your view)

create a array or object (lets call it $all_sales)

```
$all_sales = array();
```

Then for each month you query add the results to $all_sales

```
$all_sales[$month] = $month_sales;
```

This is done at the end for each right after the query

At the end you should have a array that has the key as the month and the values of the order_price. Pass this into your view in your controller

```
return view('some_view_file', ['all_sales' => $all_sales]);
```

In your view you can then do

```
@foreach($all_sales as $month=>$sales)
    {{$month}} {{$sales}}
@endofreach
```

This will display the month and the sales amount

Comment: Attempt to read property "order_price" on int
i faced such error i am new to laravel and software sorry

Comment: can you do var_dump($month_sales) and post the output?

Comment: string(7) "1324.63"
string :/

Comment: $integerIDs = array_map('intval', json_decode($year_sales, true));  I tried this code but it didn't work

Comment: $month_sales = Order::where('created_at','>=',$formatted_date)->sum('order_price');
            $int = (int)$month_sales;
            $year_sales[$month] = $int;
            $month++; This code worked, thanks for your interest

Comment: updated code instead of $month_sales->order_price just use the variable $month_sales